# sending signal with a size_t variable from a thread is not received in the other thread's slot

Tags: qt

I have these 2 signals :

```
void dataSampled(size_t a);
void error(const QString& message);
```

Elsewhere :

```
    m_acquisitionThread = new QThread(this);
    m_acquisitionManager = new AcquisitionManager();
    QObject::connect(m_acquisitionManager, &AcquisitionManager::dataSampled,
                     this,                 &Application::onDataSampled); // this Application pointer
    QObject::connect(m_acquisitionManager, &AcquisitionManager::error,
                     this,                 &Application::showError); // this Application pointer
    m_acquisitionManager->moveToThread(m_acquisitionThread);
    m_acquisitionThread->start();
```

AcquisitionManager is an object moved to a thread, Application lives in the "main" thread.

When I send signals to Application, the slot connected to dataSampled which requires a size_t is not executed, changing size_t by an int (only the signal, the slot can remain size_t) or even removing it fixes the issue. This is really strange, has anyone an idea why the signal is not sent ? In an another application (but single threaded), I tested that size_t are sent from a signal to a slot without a problem (but again the context is different).

```
void AcquisitionManager::executeDataAcquisition()
{
    emit dataSampled(666); // onDataSampled is never executed (only if I change signal type from size_t to an int or something else)
    emit error("foobar"); // Application::showError is always executed !
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting with Qt::QueuedConnection? That should take care of it without having to register it as a meta type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

registering size_t fixed the issue :

```
 qRegisterMetaType<size_t>("size_t");
```

But, isn't size_t a primitive type like int ?

Comment: See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42106 probably. `std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>` and other headers as an alias for some real primitive type. It's not totally primitive, even though it _is_ the result of the built-in `sizeof` operator... Such is life in C++, where certain parts of the stdlib are essential to use core features.

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for the clarification !